# Android :How to implement the button action

Tags: email, button

Guys i created a button now this button is basically for email so when i click this button it should open the email app with the email address written so that whoever uses the app can just click on it and start typing his mail so please guys can you tell me how to implement this

Comment: please show what you have done so far

Comment: <a href="mailto:someone@example.com?Subject=Hello%20again" target="_top">

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is to *create a link* with the *anchor tag* `<a></a>` and set its **href** attribute to "**mailto:exampleemail@example.com**" where you can give the email address of the authority you want that mail program to send the email.

For example if you want to send an email to the address "youremail@example.com" the code for the creating the button will be as follow:

```
<a href="mailto:youremail@example.com"><button>Email Us</button></a>
```

This will create a button with the text **Email Us** and will open the mail program with the address **youremail@example.com** as the to address on clicking.